# How to convert "/Date(epoch time)/" string in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a json file where all the dates in the json are in `/Date(1602949450000)/`

the json is also nested. is there a generic way to parse all of `/Date()/` into the timestamp?

I tried `regexp_replace` but I cannot convert the capture group into a timestamp.

```
regexp_replace("value", "\\/Date\\((\\-?\\d*?)([\\+\\-]\\d*)?\\)\\/","$1")
```

Comment: I can help you, but i'll need a bit more info. is it in utc?

Comment: Why do you have so many backslashes?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct, but the issue seems to be `"$1"`. When I ran the code with a `1` instead worked for me:

```py
dates_df = dates_df.withColumn(
    'date_extracted',
    F.regexp_extract("date", "\\/Date\\((\\-?\\d*?)([\\+\\-]\\d*)?\\)\\/", 1)
)
```

A more simple regex which does the same thing would be:

```py
dates_df = dates_df.withColumn(
    'date_extracted',
    F.regexp_extract("date", "^.+(\d{13}).+$", 1)
)
```